# Nine patch image support in UWP

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I want to create a textbox with a background of a bubble message(such as in instant messaging apps).

The text can be in different lengths.

In android I solved this problem just by using 9 patch image format.

Is there any support for this format in UWP? If not, how should I solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [NineGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Image_NineGrid).
[image]

Nine-grid rendering enables you to preserve the original dimensions of the corners (boxes 1, 3, 7, and 9). The top and bottom (boxes 2 and 8) are stretched horizontally only, and the sides (boxes 4 and 6) are stretched vertically only. The center (box 5) is stretched in both dimensions.

Code :

```
<Image Source="Images/9grid.bmp" NineGrid="30,20,30,20" />
```

Comment: How can I set it as the background of a textblock? or as the background of grid?

Comment: @JackPot16  this maybe helpful .:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761186/how-to-create-a-speech-bubble-in-uwp

Answer (score 0):

Place your **TextBlock** inside **ViewBox**. Set necessary dimensions:

```
<Grid Width="500" Height="200">
    <Ellipse Fill="PaleTurquoise"/>

    <Viewbox>
        <TextBlock Text="asd asdfpoiwe werolwejr ergfg qwe" FontSize="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Also this can be achieved via `Composition.UI API`. Let me know if you need.