# Create UWP speech bubble control that scales based on content

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to create a speech bubble control for my UWP app in c#/XAML that scales based on it's content.
It's based on a the following questing:

[How to create a speech bubble in UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761186/how-to-create-a-speech-bubble-in-uwp/43768218)

The problem with the link above is, it does not work with transparency in brushes(=>borders are visible).

[image: Result of the link above]

I know I could use a `Polygon` and just set the `Stretch` property but with that solution I would also stretch the triangle not just the content rectangle.

So I thought about extending `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape` (like `Rectangle`, `Circle`, `Polygon`, `...` do) but I'm unable to find any documentation about how to do this.

Summary:

- A speech bubble control that works with transparent brushes and non transparent border brushes.
- It should scales based on it's content.
- Only the content rectangle should scale/stretch not the triangle.

Comment: Interesting question, my opinion is that you will have to draw it in the code, but let's see what other people say.

Comment: So you want to set "background" of the bubble and a different brush for the border. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Yes I want for example a `Black` border and `Acrylic` as fill color.

Comment: @ivan-ičin Yes, was planing this by extending `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape` but I was unable to find any example/documentation about how to do it.

Comment: multiple way to do this, but whats your opinion about to use path data with viewbox ? where path data will help you to generate shape and viewbox will resize the content.

Comment: If you want to use transparency, then there's one way - you need to draw it as a whole, or you might encounter "glitches", "see through" and other unnecessary borders.

Comment: If there is a way to not scale the triangle only the rectangle - sure!

Comment: Isn't this possible by extending `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape` and then draw it based on the current size of the new shape?

Comment: And there use a `Polygon` for the shape